# How can I plot the frequency response of the equation below using MATLAB?

Tags: transfer-function, matlab, math

$$\boxed{\dfrac{V_{\text{out}}(j\omega)}{V_{\text{in}}(j\omega)}=\dfrac{2\times10^9}{(1+10j\omega)(100\times10^3j\omega+20\times10^3j\omega+2\times10^9-20\times10^3j\omega}}$$

and
$$\dfrac{V_{\text{out}}(j\omega)}{V_{\text{in}}(j\omega)}=\dfrac{j\omega LR_1R_2}{(j\omega L)((1+j\omega C R_2)(j\omega LR_2+j\omega LR_1+R_1R_2)-j\omega LR_1)}$$

I am having a hard time figuring out how can I translate them into symbolic math or what I will do to them to get their frequency response plots.

Comment: Do you know how to plot *some* function of a single variable? Symbolic math is not required here.

Comment: It's been a moment since I used MATLAB but you could define in the terminal or in a script \$s=tf('s');\$ and then you replace 'jw' in your equation with 's'. If you call your transfer function T, then all you need to do is \$bode(T)\$ and it should plot the magnitude and phase responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vectors to represent a transfer function in MATLAB, and then you can use the `bode(sys)` function to plot the magnitude and phase response

```
b = 2e9;
a = conv([10 1],[1e5 2e9]);
sys = tf(b,a);
bode(sys);
```

If you want to do it from scratch, you can create a vector of frequencies and plot the function against them.

```
w = logspace(0,8,200);
sys = 2e9/((10*j*w + 1)*(1e5*j*w + 2e9));
mag = abs(sys);
semilogx(w,mag);
```

If you’re new to MATLAB you may need to go to the [Mathworks Website](https://www.mathworks.com/) to see what some of these functions do.